# s3.headObject is making an unexpected item

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload some data from a website using the aws.sdk for javascript.

I want the data to appear in folders for ease of navigation and organisation for my colleagues.  I realise that S3 doesn't really have folders, but that things just appear as a folder in the broswer if the name ends with '/'.

I have the following code to create the folder (called an album, since I followed [this][1] tutorial)

```
function createAlbum(albumName) {
albumName = albumName.trim();
if (!albumName) {
  return alert("Album names must contain at least one non-space character.");
}

if (albumName.indexOf("/") !== -1) {
  return alert("Album names cannot contain slashes.");
}
var albumKey = encodeURIComponent(albumName);
s3.headObject({ Key: albumKey }, function(err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    return alert("Album already exists.");
  }
  if (err.code !== "NotFound") {
    return alert("There was an error creating your album: " + err.message);
  }
  s3.putObject({ Key: albumKey }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return alert("There was an error creating your album: " + err.message);
    }
    alert("Successfully created album.");
  });
});
```

}

This is mostly okay and I can then upload a bunch of data into the folder called 'albumName' and it all looks good in the console (which is what my colleagues and myself will mostly be using).  However, the code also creats an (empty) file with called whatever 'albumName' was, see below for a copy-and-paste from the console.

```
QZ2COwrbZ0kXsudR    -   August 2, 2021, 17:59:31 (UTC+01:00)    0 B Standard

QZ2COwrbZ0kXsudR/   Folder  -   - -
```

This is an unwanted outcome.

Could you explain to me why this empty file is being made, and how I can avoid it?

Thanks
[1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured out what was going on.  The code in the snippet above is making the file.  The next bit of code (that I haven't included above or here) then uploads the individual files with the name `QZ2COwrbZ0kXsudR/file_name.ext` and thats what is making the directory.  So the code above is good for checking for previous existence, but isn't necessary to actually make the directory.  This relates back to previous posts about how folders don't really exist in S3.